# Laravel : highest id used in a column

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a table `gifts_sent` with a model `GiftSent` and having the following columns.

`id`,`gift_id`,`sender_id`,`receiver_id`

Note : `sender_id` and `receiver_id` are foreign keys.

suppose that user with id `1` have sent 11 gifts and user with id `2` have sent 9 gifts and so on for the other users.

How can i achieve that with laravel eloquent or query builder ?

Note : Its for ranking, That which user have sent most gifts.

I have came up with the following logic but its not correct.

```
App\User::join('gift_sents', function($builder){
    $builder->on('gift_sents.receiver_id', '=', 'users.id');
    })
    ->select('users.*', DB::raw('COUNT(gift_sents.receiver_id) as total_posts'))
    ->groupBy('gift_sents.id')
    ->orderBy('total_posts', 'ASC')
    ->limit(3)->get();
```

Comment: The query itself could be `SELECT sender_id, SUM(*) sent FROM my_table GROUP BY sender_id ORDER BY sent DESC LIMIT 1` - although this wouldn't account for ties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you will have to define relationship with User and GiftSent Model.
Get the sender_id who has  sent maximum count of gifts. Fetch all the user using relation ('with').

```
App\GiftSent::with('userRelationName')
->select('sender_id', DB::raw('COUNT(*) as giftCount'))
->groupBy('sender_id')
->orderBy(DB::raw('COUNT(*)'))
->get();
```

Other solution is to use join but it will be complicated and costly.

Comment: Thanks mate but your query have an error ! Please have a look